# A priori and asymptotic complexity level

Tags: c, function, complexity-theory

How to determine the a priori and asymptotic complexity of following program code?

```
#include<stdio.h>


int br_nacina_zaba(int br_lopoca, int tren_poz, int korak) {  
    if (korak == 18) return 0;
    else if (tren_poz == br_lopoca) return 1;
    else if (tren_poz <= 0 && korak != 0) return 0;
    else if (tren_poz > br_lopoca) return 0;
    else return
               br_nacina_zaba(br_lopoca, tren_poz + 2, korak + 1)
             + br_nacina_zaba(br_lopoca, tren_poz + 3, korak + 1)
             + br_nacina_zaba(br_lopoca, tren_poz - 2, korak + 1)
             + br_nacina_zaba(br_lopoca, tren_poz - 3, korak + 1);
}
```

So I need to know the complexity of function `br_nacina_zaba(n,0,0)`.

Comment: What's a "complexity" level? And what's an "a priori" one?

Comment: Could you format your code so that we can read it?

Comment: a priori means duration of function in worst case scenario, i don't know how to translate it in english :S  
it has the following formula: O(g(n))

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, `br_nacina_zaba(n,0,0)` is in O(1). The maximum depth of the (quaternary) call tree is limited by 19 in the function's first LOC:

`korak` gets incremented in each recursive call. If you start with `korak=0` and call the function at most 4 times in each recursive step, you'll have at most 4^18 recursive calls. 4^18 doesn't depend on n, hence the function is in O(1).

Comment: Philip tnx.
Can you also say your opinion about the asymptotic complexity?

Comment: The asymptotic complexity is the function `f(n) = 4^18`. To avoid further confusion, it might be helpful if you properly defined what you mean by "asymptotic complexity" and "a priori complexity". In my understanding, the asymptotic complexity is a function which gives an upper bound for the number of recursive calls. The *order* of `f` is constant. Hence, `f`, and therefore `br_whatever()`, is in O(1).

Comment: IMHO u are right. but let me give u an example of asymptotic so u can see what that is i say of:
  
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < i; i++)

so here is O(n^2) and asymptotic complexity is n^2/2 (because the sum of i is n(n+1)/2)

Comment: I think you mean "...an example of a priori complexity...". In that case, what you mean by "a priori complexity" is just the "order of asymptotic complexity". I'm not an English native speaker myself, so I once had similar troubles...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean "complexity of function", but I run your function on codepad ( http://codepad.org/jFUW1ATj ) and got this result

```
br_nacina_zaba(1, 0, 0) was called 5 times.
br_nacina_zaba(2, 0, 0) was called 5 times.
br_nacina_zaba(3, 0, 0) was called 9 times.
br_nacina_zaba(4, 0, 0) was called 77 times.
br_nacina_zaba(5, 0, 0) was called 33445 times.
br_nacina_zaba(6, 0, 0) was called 1048573 times.
br_nacina_zaba(7, 0, 0) was called 15530681 times.
```